# Google search result showing unknown results

Tags: google

I'm facing serious issues with Google search results. 'Till yesterday everything was fine. Today when I search with my top ranking keyword, Google gives some other URL with my website's title & description. If I open that site it's getting redirected to my site.

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I don't really feel this question is relevant to Stack Overflow - it's not really about programming of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

This site is probably scraping your site and some code on your site is redirecting back to you which is unintentional on their part. What you need to do is find the IP address of the other site and block it using htaccess. That will prevent them from being able to access your content. Once you do their site should literally disappear immediately and their search rankings should fall away soon.

Here's what the htaccess would look like assuming an IP Address of 123.123.123.123:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.123.123.123
allow from all
```

I would also add [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to your pages just to make sure Google knows you are the original author of that content.

Comment: Will this make the scraper's site disappear if they've already stored OP's content on their server? Won't it just stop the redirect from bringing visitors back to OP's site?

Comment: If they're scraping the site while it's live it will stop it immediately. If they already downloaded the content it won't help. Sites like this usually automate the whole thing and live scraping the site is the easiest way to do it as it doesn't require storing any real data on their side. It also make sure they have a perfect copy.